# Static variables in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

There is [an article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312607#4) that recommends to store ASP.NET application state in static members of *HttpApplication* class (in Global.asax.cs).

What about storing application state in static members of **other classes**?

I tried to do so and it seems that there are several instances of these variables can exist (single instance per AppDomain?). Is it true and should we always use only *Application* class's static fields? Or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works pretty well and it's better than `Application` in many cases (it's strongly typed, for instance). Just make sure you are aware of threading and locking issues.

As a personal experience, I've managed to cache configuration information for ASP.NET app in a `static` class in a couple Web sites.

Answer (score 3):

You can run into big problems with static variables if you are doing anything more than just reading from them in a web application.  Asp.net is a multithreaded environment.  The application collection does locking for you during a Get or a Set with a lock.  If you use static variables, then there is no lock in place.

I would suggest using the web.config to store all your read only variables in it's own section.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true and should we always use only Application class's static fields?

Yes.  User-specific data (session data) should not go here.

All the users of your site are in the same application instance, and so will share the same static variables.  It's definitely not a good replacement for the session, for example.

Comment: I ran into that on code I inherited from another developer. The client was trying to figure out why small-scale multi-user tests kept failing with weird data. When I saw the code and explained the issue, the result was a collective *headslap!* Fairly easy fix, and now we have a client for life. :)