# Question about static Objects .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

Are static variable values the same within one session or are their values the same at application server level?

Comment: It's incorrect question:static object - its common object for full .NET application - its incorrect to tell about him in Session objet or Application obect Web Server context. But answer on your question, one static object - its one common object in all sessions in your web-application.

Comment: A couple of searches on google/SO would have helped your doubt and saved time. :) The first result on SO gave me this --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853837/static-variables-in-asp-net . Search url --> http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+static+variables

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They're at an `AppDomain` level - that's the same for all static variables, whether they're in ASP.NET or not.

So:

- If you use the same class from different AppDomains, you'll get separate variables
- If your AppDomain is recycled, you'll get separate variables
- If two requests go to different machines, you'll get separate variables
- If two *concurrent* requests hit the same AppDomain, they can mess with each other (so things like `count++` aren't safe)

Comment: I think that last one means there is no locking and that's what may cause dirty reads, right?

Comment: @LordCover: Well, not just dirty reads - but non-atomic increments, unless you're careful. `count++` is a three-stage operation: read, increment, write. Two threads could both read, both increment, and then both write, resulting in a single increment overall.

Comment: If two requests go to different machines, you'll get separate variables.. is this means that request initiated from 2 different machines??

Comment: @Ahsan: No, I mean if you've got a server farm for the web app, and two requests - whether from the same machine or not - hit different web servers.

Answer (score 0):

I think as long as iis process is there the static variable will hold its value

Answer (score 0):

The variable will still in memory until the restart of the application.